# Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Middleware.IFunctionsWorkerMiddleware Unit Testing

Tags: asp.net-core-middleware

Looking for some examples on how to setup unit testing around IFunctionsWorkerMiddleware.  All the examples I've found are for MVC and not function apps.

Example for MVC, but looking for .net 6 using function apps

```
using var host = await new HostBuilder() .ConfigureWebHost(webBuilder => { webBuilder .UseTestServer() .ConfigureServices(services => { services.AddMyServices(); }) .Configure(app => { app.UseMiddleware<MyMiddleware>(); }); }) .StartAsync(); var response = await host.GetTestClient().GetAsync("/")
```

Thanks in advance.

In order to test the middleware we need to spin up a host using HostBuilder; as part of configuring host builder we can stipulate it needs to use the test server (an in-memory webserver).  This is what we will make request against an what should be executing the middleware. Every single example I've found and tried are all for MVC  and nothing for function apps.  and every attempt pretty much results in a gRPC issue (gRPC is spun uo by the function app process by default, I cannot find where/how to not set it up).